# Generalized pigeonhole principle: 15 workstations and 10 servers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

> **Q:** Suppose that a computer science laboratory has 15 workstations and 10 servers. A cable can be used to directly connect a workstation
>   to a server. For each server, only one direct connection to that
>   server can be active at any time. We want to guarantee that at any
>   time any set of 10 or fewer workstations can simultaneously access
>   different servers via direct connections. What is the minimum number
>   of direct connections needed to achieve this goal?

This is an example from Rosen's *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications*. The given solution to this example consists of 2 parts if I understood correctly.

The first part includes finding the number of connections like the following:

> Suppose that we label the workstations $W_1, W_2, ..., W_{15}$ and the
>   servers $S_1, S_2, ..., S_{10}$. Furthermore, suppose that we connect
>   $W_k$ to $S_k$ for $k = 1,2, ..., 10$ and each of $W_{11}, W_{12}$,
>   $W_{13}, W_{14}$, and $W_{15}$ to all 10 servers. We have a total of 60
>   direct connections.

Then I guess some kind of proof by contradiction is given to show that less than 60 connections is impossible.

> Now suppose there are fewer than 60 direct connections between
>   workstations and servers. Then some server would be connected to at
>   most $\lfloor 59/10\rfloor= 5 $ workstations.(If all servers were
>   connected to at least six workstations, there would be at least $6.10$
>   $= 60$ direct connections.) This means that the remaining nine servers are not enough to allow the other 10 workstations to simultaneously
>   access different servers. Consequently, at least 60 direct connections
>   are needed.

But I can't understand this part. How is it concluded that remaining nine servers are insufficient when at most 59 connections are used?

Answer (score 8):

I’m assuming that you understood why there must be a server connected to at most $5$ workstations if there are only $59$ direct connections.

There’s no harm in labelling the servers so that server $S_1$ is connected to $5$ or fewer workstations, and there’s no harm in assuming that the workstations to which $S_1$ is directly connected are among the last five, $W_{11},W_{12},W_{13},W_{14}$, and $W_{15}$, so that $S_1$ is *not* directly connected to any of the ten workstations $W_1,W_2,\ldots,W_{10}$. In other words, every direct connection from one of these ten workstations is to one of the nine servers $S_2,S_3,\ldots,S_{10}$. This means that the ten workstations $W_1,W_2,\ldots,W_{10}$ cannot simultaneously directly access all ten servers: none of them has a direct connection to $S_1$, so if they all directly access a server simultaneously, two of them must access the same server. This contradicts our guarantee that *every* set of ten (or fewer) workstations can simultaneously directly access all ten servers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one question please. It's easy to see that since we want up to 10 connections is guaranteed between WS and servers. So, 10 connections has to be part of the question, but then the extra part I still don't understand, "We connect 10 workstations to 10 servers using 10 direct connections. But 10 workstation at any time can come from any of the 15, and direct connections are available only from a select 10. So, we must now guarantee that whichever 5 workstations are coming extra". Can you please explain the why we need to connect extra 5 WS to all servers?

Comment: Out of first 10 direct connections, we might get 1 up to 10 direct connections. So how we guarantee that we will get 1 connection first? Then, we connect extra 5 WS to all other servers, which, honestly, I still don't get why we do that in the first place? How that will guarantee that we get up to 10 WS connected to servers please?

Comment: @Avra: I’m not sure that I understand what you’re asking. Are you asking why the arrangement with $60$ direct connections that is described in the second quote block in the question actually ensures that any set of $10$ workstations can simultaneously access different servers? Given any set of $10$ workstations, suppose that $n$ of them are numbered $10$ or less; then $10-n$ have numbers in the set $\{11,12,13,14,15\}$. Each of those $n$ workstations is connected to the server with the same number; that leaves $10-n$ servers available for the other $10-n$ workstations in the set, and those ...

Comment: ... $10-n$ workstations are connected to all $10$ servers, so we can assign each of them to a different one of the $10-n$ servers that are still available.

Comment: Thank you. I mean why we can not just let the first 10 workstations have 10 direction connections to servers without needing to to connect 5 extra workstations to to all servers (50 direction connections)?

2) How we can even guarantee that we can have 10 direction connections from the first 10 WS in the first place please?

Comment: @Avra: I don’t see how you get $50$ direct connections. Remember, there must be enough direct connections so that is $S$ is **any** set of ten of the $15$ workstations, there is a direct connection from each server to a different workstation in $S$. \\ We’re allowed to set up any direct connections that we want. The problem is to show that we can set up $60$ of them with the desired problem, and that $59$ of them are not enough to do that.